# URL Hack functionality within Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, urlhacking

I have a fun one.

Salesforce1 users need an SF1 action button to:

1. Create a new case with its standard and custom lookup fields auto-populated from lookup fields associated from the custom object.
2. Have the page auto redirect to the newly created case. Edit-view preferred, but not necessary.

I already have a custom java launch button that works fine within the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here is to have an action button that routes to a Visualforce page, which in turn uses a custom controller to create & initialise the case before redirecting the user to the edit page. URL hacks are called hacks for a reason, and now more than ever they're at risk of breaking in the next year.

Even better: see if you can use Lightning to do the same (this might not be possible right now, I genuinely don't know).